# FAB Button animation for hiding and showing operation

Tags: css, typescript, angular2-template

I have created a set of FAB Buttons in Angular2. I want to add the animation so them so that they are displayed one after the another for hide and show operation. How shall i do it with the animations, Can anyone please help me in Animation.

```
 <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" aria-label="New Task" [disabled]="!this.isPermission" (click)='FabToggle = !FabToggle'>
                                <md-icon style="color:white;">menu</md-icon>
                            </button>
                            <div class="fab-actions" [ngClass]="{'fabActionsHide':!FabToggle,'fabActionsShow':FabToggle}">
                                <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='reloadApi()'>
                                    <md-icon svgIcon="refresh"></md-icon>
                                </button>
                                <button [disabled]="!this.isPermission" md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='generatePDF()'>
                                    <md-icon svgIcon="pdf"></md-icon>
                                </button>
                                <button [disabled]="!this.isPermission" md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='generateCSV()'>
                                    <md-icon svgIcon="csv"></md-icon>
                                </button>
                                <button [disabled]="!this.isPermission || !checkin_entries" md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)="addModal.show();FabToggle = !FabToggle">
                                    <md-icon style="color:white;">add</md-icon>
                                </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got this while searching for your answer. As I'm not able to comment to your question, so posting it in answer section.

(Click-only FAB) Section

[Check this](http://materializecss.com/buttons.html)